# How to autoSize cells in the jxls template, so that generated report also will have autosized cells

Tags: jxls

I have used jxls template to generate my excel report. The report data is not aligned properly. I need ,

Report's cells to be autosized based on the data length - both rowwise & columnwise.

I have tried to used jxls comments, but didnt get correct comments to be added in the cells

jx:autoRowHeight(lastCell="B2")

i couldn't attache output image here,I need below things,

Report's cells to be autosized based on the data length - both rowwise & columnwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust column and to row to the certain width/height, there are methods of class `WritableSheet` called `setColumnView` and `setRowView` which do this preety well.